# Generate a list of web queries

Tags: python, sql

I'm pretty new at this and I'm trying to figure out a way to look up a list of websites automatically. I have a very large list of companies and essentially I'd want the algorithm to type the company into Google, click the first link (most likely the company website) and figure out whether the company matches the target industry (ice cream distributors) or has anything to do with the industry. The way I'd want to check for this is by seeing if the home page contains any of the key words in a given dictionary (let's say, 'chocolate, vanilla, ice cream, etc'). I would really appreciate some help with this - thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a combination of requests and lxml. To accomplish this you could do something similar to this.
    import requests
    from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
    from lxml import html

use `requests` or `grequests` to get the html from all the pages.

```
queries = ['cats', 'dogs']
queries = [requests.get(x) for x in queries]
data = [x.text for x in queries]
```

parse the html with `lxml` and extract the first link on each page.

```
data = [html.document_fromstring(x) for x in data]
sel = CSSSelector('h3.r a')
links = [sel(x)[0] for x in data]
```

finally grab the html from all the first results.

```
pages = [requests.get(a.attrib['href'] for a in links]
```

this will give you an html string each of the pages you want. From there you should be able to simply search for the words you want in the pages html. You might find a `counter` helpful.

Comment: Hey, this is great! Thank You! I just had a quick follow-up to this - what if I have websites in different languages? Is there a way I could use chrome translate into english each time so that it could search just based on my english dictionary?